# Query MySQL database without having to create models Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot to create a web app. I need to store and query a list of patients however the table Patients has 30+ Columns so it is too big to use a java model. I was wondering if there is a way where I can query ( using sql script ) my Patient table and then display the list on html

Comment: Why would it be too big for a java model? Have used models with more fields and columns... Looks like you are afraid of something that isn't really a problem. Nonetheless you can always use JDBC to query the database, but you need to put the information into an object anyway.

Comment: I am creating a paitent treating app so I am dealing with a huge amount of data which I am not used to doing.

Comment: as @M.Deinum said, there wont be any performance issues too. One optimization would be combining multiple attributes into a json string and pass it until the UI without processing in Java. This is a common design I see when we do not want to filter data by set of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but I think you need a model but you can simplified this model. You can add properties as you will use. Incoming SQL query response assign to your simple model. Also I think it's good that you want to simplify the model. It will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "big model".

I'd recommend using [JdbcTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate) f you mean "I don't want all that JPA/Hibernate machinery".  It's the lightest, simplest way to interact with relational databases using SQL.

You don't need a complex object model.  Map each row into a `Map` of column name/value pairs and return a `List` of them for each query.  Simple.